# Spring Security always authenticates with custom JdbcDaoImpl

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am currently trying to get my spring security based Webapp to authenticate the entered Username to several database columns. To be exact, I want the User to be able to use an Username OR Email OR Alias to login. Therefore I have written the following JdbcDaoImpl (the email feature is not yet implemented, but it should not make a difference)

```
package de.dlr.gsoc.gssng.springSecurity;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.ParameterizedRowMapper;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

public class CustomJDBCDaoImpl extends JdbcDaoImpl{



public CustomJDBCDaoImpl() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super();
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl#loadUserAuthorities(java.lang.String)
 */
@Override
protected List<GrantedAuthority> loadGroupAuthorities(String username) {
    String sql = "SELECT GroupAuthorities.Authority FROM Groups, GroupAuthorities, GroupMembers, Users WHERE (Users.Username = ? OR Users.Alias = ?) AND GroupMembers.Users_UserID = Users.UserID AND GroupMembers.Groups_GroupID = Groups.GroupID AND GroupAuthorities.Groups_GroupID = Groups.GroupID";



    JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(getDataSource());

    CustomAuthority returnAuth = template.queryForObject(sql, new Object[] {username, username},  new AuthorityMapper());

    ArrayList<GrantedAuthority> returnList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

    returnList.add(returnAuth);

    return returnList;
}

private class CustomAuthority implements GrantedAuthority
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6983133192699859170L;
    private String Authority;

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority#getAuthority()
     */
    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Authority;
    }

    public CustomAuthority(String _auth)
    {
        this.Authority = _auth;
    }
}

private class AuthorityMapper implements ParameterizedRowMapper<CustomAuthority> {

    @Override
    public CustomAuthority mapRow(ResultSet rs, int arg1) throws SQLException {
        return new CustomAuthority(rs.getString("Authority"));
    }

}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl#loadUsersByUsername(java.lang.String)
 */
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {

    String sql = "SELECT Users.Username, Users.Password, Users.Enabled FROM Users WHERE Users.Username = ? OR Users.Alias = ?";


    JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(getDataSource());

    User returnUser = template.queryForObject(sql, new UserMapper(), new Object[] {username, username});


    return returnUser;
}

private class UserMapper implements ParameterizedRowMapper<User> {

    @Override
    public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int arg1) throws SQLException {
        return new User(rs.getString("Username"), rs.getString("Password"), rs.getBoolean("Enabled"), true, true, true, loadGroupAuthorities(rs.getString("Username")));
    }

}
```

}

It loads the userDetails just fine from the database. The password loaded is also correct and in encrypted form. However, now the user can enter ANY password he likes and will always be authenticated. If I remove all the overwritten methods and return to the standard Queries setup in the web.xml file everything works perfectly.

Am I missing something? Do I have to overwrite my RememberMeAuthenticationProvider as well?

Comment: the "remember me" has no relation to this. can you paste here your spring-beans.xml file? so we can see your configuration...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could to do your own customAuthenticationProvider:

Xml configuration

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">  
<authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>
```

Java code

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private static final String CREDENCIALES_INCORRECTAS = "Username o password incorrectos";

    private static final String CUENTA_IS_NOT_ENABLED = "La cuenta de usuario no ha sido activada.";

    @Autowired
    private UsersService usersService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoderSha256 passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = authentication.getName();
        String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();

                //Find by username or email
        User user = usersService.findUserForAuthentication(username);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException(CREDENCIALES_INCORRECTAS);
        }

        if (!user.isEnabled()) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException(CUENTA_IS_NOT_ENABLED);
        }
        password = passwordEncoder.encodeSha256Password(password);

        if (!password.equals(user.getPassword())) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException(CREDENCIALES_INCORRECTAS);
        }

        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = user
                .getAuthorities();

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(),
                password, authorities);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> arg0) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser()` loads the UserDetails from the DB. Then, `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.additionalAuthenticationChecks()` checks that the passwords match (after it encrypts the password that the user just entered). It delegated the call to `passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid()`. Hence, you have to make sure what is your passwordEncoder.

If you paste here your beans.xml, it will be easier to see the answer.